# How Prisma returns last inserted row reliably, can I mimic this with a procedure call?

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure-functions, prisma2

I'm using Prisma on Azure Function App, so it is serverless with one prisma client (const prisma = new PrismaClient();) and I don't close the connection after a given function run.

In the beginning I created records with `prisma.myTable.create({...` call, where the response was the created row. From that I needed the auto incremented Id, to make queries in other tables.

As the project progressed I was given a MySQL procedure call which creates the proper entry in the table. It helped to reduce the need of some variables from my side, but introduced a new problem of reliably get the created row id. I call the procedure like this:

```
const rawQuery = `call EM_ADDMSG('${myVar1}', '${myVar2}', '${myVar3}', NULL, NULL, NULL, '${myVar4}', @id);`;

await prisma.$executeRaw(rawQuery);
```

We tried 2 approach. One is the session variable, which now I understand why it fails.

```
const rawId = 'select @id';
const response = await prisma.$queryRaw(rawId);
return response[0]['@id'];
```

If multiple requests arrives simultaneously the response contains sometimes the same id. I believe it is expected since I have only one session and it seems even I made 2 inserts, still get back the previous @id from the session.

The second approach is to track the id in a different table.
After I insert read that table and delete the row. I tried to use prismas `delete()` without querying, because that returns the deleted row also.
In slow pace it is also working, but with multiple almost simultaneous I run into an error where there is nothing to delete. (There is also another identifier in that table which I'm using for selecting that row). I get the error:

*An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. Record to delete does not exist.*

It seem, the sequence is *insert, insert, delete* but the second delete fails, because the table is empty.

The safest solution so far was to use `await prisma.$transaction([...` for inserting and deleting that row, but on that cases I get the error:

*code: 1213, message: "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction", state: "40001"*

It is at least consistent, so there is no id mixup.

Is there a solution to this problem keeping the procedure? This is a messaging app where there is a possibility that some requests arrives at the same time.

Comment: Look for how Prisma provides `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.